# Manage memoryStream when donwload files from Azure Blob

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on creating wrapper for download files from Azure Blob Storage.
I have a simple model for file

```
public class File
{
    public Stream Data { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
}
```

my method to download a file looks like this

```
private async Task<File> GetFile(string name, string path = null)
{
    var blockBlob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(GetKey(name, path));
    await blockBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return new File(
        name: name,
        path: path: blockBlob.Uri.ToString(),
        data: memoryStream,
        size: blockBlob.Properties.Length);
}
```

Question: is it ok that I create a memoryStream and never dispose it? Should I pass memoryStream as a parameter and move responsibility for lifetime to caller? If yes, how can I do that with mu model?

Comment: It's not advisable to have the caller be responsible to managing the stream (in fact in your implementation you should wrap the use of memorystream in a using statement) - why not  have the data property to be block / text rather than Stream (depending on what it is you're actually storing) ?

Comment: What do you mean? How can I wrap memorystream  to using if it should be used on caller side, in other case it will be disposed in GetFile method.

Comment: The memory stream is create in a non static method so it is create on the execution stack and automatically gets disposed when you exit the method.  The stack gets popped so all the data is destroyed.

Comment: Do you mean that everything is ok with design?

Comment: @jdweng You’re right- it’s not required to have a using for a MemoryStream (see note in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.8). So I guess the code as it is is ok

Comment: @auburg, please post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MemoryStream doesn't require explicit disposal according to the docs (see note in [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/…](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.8)) so you're current design is fine.